# How to print bulk files from library on file upload on SharePoint on-premise?

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload

I have SharePoint on-premise server and I want to print bulk files printing from SharePoint library on files upload automatically. So I looked the few tutorial but seems not working fine.

Can anyone please help out is there any solutions or customized things available?

Comment: Are you saying you want to print the document via an office printer as soon as the file has been uploaded to a document library?

Comment: @CallumCrowley Yes. Please advise if there is list of way to print the document in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no OOB solutions or customized codes to achieve this in SharePoint.